# How to remove certain versions in bzr repository?

Tags: bazaar, bzr-svn

Say I have 10 versions in bzr repository, and I want to remove the last 2 versions. I tried "bzr revert -r -3", but it just revert the files to the second last version, and the following "bar log" still shows all 10 versions in the repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command to do that is `uncommit`:

```
bzr uncommit -r-3
```

The last two revisions will be removed from the branch.